# Run a query to check consistency in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-analysis

I need some help with a SQL query and logic in general. (Using MSSQL Server)

I need to check the consistency of payments at certain retailers over a period of three months.

So I've got a table with all my transactions and the following columns:

`TransactionID , AccountNumber , Retailer, Date` .... (few other irrelevant ones)

Now one `Accountnumber` could have many transaction `ID`s. (One account could decide to make several payments during one month).

I have 4 unique retailers' ids, let's call them `(101,102,103,104)`

Now for consistency I want to get the following data:

The count of transactions where there was only one payment per account for the month at  each retailer.

So I'd have:

```
 | # Payments For Month | Retailer | Number of Transactions
 | 1 Payment            | 101      | 5000
 ...
```

But I also want to see how many transactions there were from accounts that made payments at multiple retailers

So I'd want something like:

```
| 2 Payments | 102 & 104 | 20
```

Which would mean that an account made 20 payments at retailer 102 & 104.

I don't as much care about how many accounts, more the amount of transactions.

I also want it broken down by month, but I've decided to do a seperate query for each month.

I've imported the data into a local DB on my personal laptop so I could go crazy, so I'll be able to try any method.

The goal of this query is to check the consistency of payments by people (accounts) at certain retailers. How many transactions do they loyally make at one retailer every month, how many transactions are there where they've gone to two retailers? or three? or all four?